# Can't event click on an SVG element after a succesfull call

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't click on the svg after getting a succesfull load event. Any clues? I'm console logging the returned SVG object, yet Im not getting any clicking action.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/tz2knqhr/
```

```
<embed src="https://www.okcode.pl/img/bg-square.svg" id="embed2" width="15%" height="auto" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>


<script>

function resolveAfter() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        let image = document.getElementById("embed2")
          resolve(image);
      })
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter();
  console.log('result',result);
  result.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    console.log("clicked")
    location.href = "http://google.com"
  })
}

asyncCall();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wrap your `embed` in an `object` so it can receive clicks. To ensure that the object always receives the click event, I'm setting `pointer-events: none` to all of its (eventual) children after the `embed` call. Also notice that the click event is set on the `parentNode` of the function return (the `object`), not the `embed`.

```js
function resolveAfter() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      let image = document.getElementById("embed2")
      resolve(image);
    })
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter();
  console.log('result', result.parentNode);

  result.parentNode.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log("made it");
    // location.href = "http://google.com"
  })
}

asyncCall();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: white;
}

object {
  display: inline-flex;
}

object * {
  /* ignore clicks to children */
  pointer-events: none;
}

object embed {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<object style="width: 15%; height: auto;">
  <embed src="https://www.okcode.pl/img/bg-square.svg" id="embed2" width="15%" height="auto" type="image/svg+xml" />
</object>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmro89u7/5/)